# Moving hierarchy with the most revisions with more performance (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have hierarchical table for my features with a parent-child relation. There was an unique constraint missing, why I have branches in the data, where multiple children relate to one parent. To add the constraint, I have to remove the branches.

```
CREATE TABLE feature_log
(
    feature_id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    revision_id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    parent_id UUID,
    project_id INTEGER,
    data_hash TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    user_id INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT pk_feature_log PRIMARY KEY (revision_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES feature_log (revision_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_feature_data FOREIGN KEY (data_hash) REFERENCES feature_data (hash),
    CONSTRAINT fk_project FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_feature_log_parent_id UNIQUE (project_id, feature_id, parent_id) -- this was missing
);

CREATE INDEX feature_log_feature_parent_id_idx on myedit.feature_log (feature_id, parent_id);
CREATE INDEX feature_log_project_id_idx on myedit.feature_log (project_id);
CREATE INDEX feature_log_parent_id_idx on myedit.feature_log (parent_id);
CREATE INDEX feature_log_feature_id_idx on myedit.feature_log (feature_id);
CREATE INDEX feature_log_data_hash_idx on myedit.feature_log (data_hash);
CREATE INDEX feature_log_find_all_idx on myedit.feature_log (parent_id, revision_id, project_id);
```

If the data_hash is NULL, the feature is deleted. If a feature doesn't have a child, it's a node feature.

To resolve this, I have the original table and two helper tables. One where the fixed data is in (feature_log_resolve), the other is to delete identified corrupt data and identified good data (feature_log_clipboard) - so there are only the features with problem left.

The problem is in resolving the last part: When a feature has multiple living node children, take that one which has the most revisions. There are around 700k features left in this part and there are to many loops it takes for days. How can I make this script a little faster?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_node_features (
  p_only_alive BOOLEAN
)
RETURNS SETOF feature_log_clipboard AS
$$
 SELECT * FROM feature_log_clipboard AS child
    WHERE (
        (p_only_alive AND child.data_hash IS NOT NULL)
        OR
        NOT p_only_alive
    )
    AND NOT
        (EXISTS
            (SELECT parent.parent_id FROM feature_log_clipboard AS parent
            WHERE parent.parent_id = child.revision_id
            AND parent.project_id = child.project_id)
        );
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_biggest_revision (
    p_only_alive BOOLEAN
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    generation INTEGER,
    feature_id UUID,
    revision_id UUID,
    parent_id UUID,
    project_id INTEGER,
    data_hash TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    user_id INTEGER,
    row_number BIGINT
) AS
$$
    WITH RECURSIVE
    feature_hierarchy(generation, feature_id, revision_id, parent_id, project_id, data_hash, created, user_id) AS
    (
        SELECT 0, firstGeneration.feature_id, firstGeneration.revision_id, firstGeneration.parent_id, firstGeneration.project_id, firstGeneration.data_hash, firstGeneration.created, firstGeneration.user_id
            FROM feature_log_clipboard AS firstGeneration
            WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT revision_id FROM feature_log_clipboard)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT parent.generation + 1, nextGeneration.feature_id, nextGeneration.revision_id, nextGeneration.parent_id, nextGeneration.project_id, nextGeneration.data_hash, nextGeneration.created, nextGeneration.user_id
            FROM feature_log_clipboard AS nextGeneration
            INNER JOIN feature_hierarchy AS parent ON nextGeneration.parent_id = parent.revision_id
    )

    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.feature_id ORDER BY p.generation DESC, p.created DESC) AS row_number
            FROM feature_hierarchy AS p
            WHERE revision_id IN (SELECT revision_id FROM get_node_features(p_only_alive))

$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_biggest_revision_hierarchy (
    p_only_alive BOOLEAN
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    feature_id UUID,
    revision_id UUID,
    parent_id UUID,
    project_id INTEGER,
    data_hash TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    user_id INTEGER,
    row_number BIGINT
) AS
$$
    WITH RECURSIVE
    biggest_revision_hierarchy AS (
        SELECT lastGeneration.feature_id, lastGeneration.revision_id, lastGeneration.parent_id, lastGeneration.project_id, lastGeneration.data_hash, lastGeneration.created, lastGeneration.user_id, lastGeneration.row_number
            FROM get_biggest_revision(p_only_alive) AS lastGeneration
            WHERE lastGeneration.row_number = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT nextGeneration.feature_id, nextGeneration.revision_id, nextGeneration.parent_id, nextGeneration.project_id, nextGeneration.data_hash, nextGeneration.created, nextGeneration.user_id, nextGeneration.user_id
            FROM feature_log_clipboard AS nextGeneration
        INNER JOIN biggest_revision_hierarchy AS child ON nextGeneration.revision_id = child.parent_id
    )

    SELECT * FROM biggest_revision_hierarchy;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_moved_features ()
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
    DELETE FROM feature_log_clipboard
    WHERE feature_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT feature_id
        FROM feature_log_resolve
        WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
    )
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';


-- copy node features of latest generation with their complete hierarchy to resolve table
INSERT INTO feature_log_resolve (feature_id, revision_id, parent_id, project_id, data_hash, created, user_id)
SELECT feature_id, revision_id, parent_id, project_id, data_hash, created, user_id FROM get_biggest_revision_hierarchy(TRUE);

-- delete whole feature_id of the node features of latest generation from clipboard
SELECT * FROM delete_moved_features();

-- copy node features of latest generation with their complete hierarchy to resolve table
INSERT INTO feature_log_resolve (feature_id, revision_id, parent_id, project_id, data_hash, created, user_id)
SELECT feature_id, revision_id, parent_id, project_id, data_hash, created, user_id FROM get_biggest_revision_hierarchy(FALSE);

-- delete whole feature_id of the node features of latest generation from clipboard
SELECT * FROM delete_moved_features();
```